# Google Drive authentication. Do I need special permissions to get full drive access in a domain?

Tags: google-drive-api

I've made an application that manages files in the google drive. During dev I used a

gmailadress:user@gmail.com

Now I'm using: user@googleappsdomain.com

and the authentication stopped working. I keep getting 401 not authorized. **Do I need special permissions to get full drive access in a domain?**

This is the error the webserver gives me.

```
{
"code" : 401,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "Invalid Credentials",
"reason" : "authError"
} ],
"message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

Error when I try the quickstart example with the other email adress. (Works fine with my gmail adress).

When i'm using OAuth 2.0 Playground I get the same 401 error with my apps address on step 3 when I request Files.List...

I found this:
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162106

Is this the setting I'm looking for? 
It doesn't say anything about the drive scope..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction.

The short answer to "Do I need special permissions to get full drive access in a domain?" is yes.

https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/YOURDOMAIN.COM/ServiceSettings#ServiceSettings/service=drive+and+docs&subtab=general

To prove to yourself that it should work, try running the "try it" at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it

From there you can work backwards through oauth playground and then your own code to see what's different.

Comment: The following steps just worked ok for me

1. Go to https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it

2. Click the "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0" box

3. Click execute

I get the expected list of files as a result. This is using my domain email address.

Since this test isn't using any of your code, it suggests you have a problem with your domain email.

Comment: Do you know when/if your apps account was migrated? 

Can you make a new email in your apps domain and try that so you can isolate it to a domain ior specific email issue?

Comment: Try https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/YOURDOMAIN.COM/ServiceSettings#ServiceSettings/service=drive+and+docs&subtab=general


There are two settings "

Allow users to install Google Drive for Mac/PC
Google Drive for Mac/PC lets you sync your files between your computer and Google Drive, so you can access your most up-to-date files from any device and easily collaborate on work with others.Learn more
Allow users to install Google Drive apps
Google Drive apps allow users to open their files in web apps installed from the Chrome Web Store

Comment: I just unchecked those two items for my domain and after doing so I get a 401. Checking them restores normal service. So it looks like your initial suspicion was correct that access to the Drive API needs to be authorised by the domain admin. I've corrected my previous answer to reflect this discovery.

Comment: I asked the domain admin and indeed I got it working. But I'm wondering if there's a way to only allow my application. We don't want the users to install whatever they want.

Comment: I had a poke around in the domain management and found a link to this video. http://www.youtube.com/v/t-HSKJaTx1w&rel=0&hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&version=3

If that doesn't do it, you might have to roll your own using the apps API https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/apps

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your credentials, and get a new set for the new user. I suspect you are using some stored credentials somewhere, or have issues with being logged into more than one account at once.

Comment: I'm not storing the credentials yet. I'm always asking a confirmation when the application starts.

Comment: My client_id and client_secret are from my normal gmail account drive api  would that be a problem?

Comment: Could it be that the google apps domain prevents access to the Drive scope?